# Posting to a friends wall with exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The exception I am getting is "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".  I know this is a well published exception but there are no rules which I can follow to get this code to work.  I am trying to post to a friends wall via the API.

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

String accessToken =  result.ExtraData["accesstoken"];
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

 dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
 arameters.message = "Testing";
```

I have managed to get my friends facebook ids and this is `facebookFriendID`

```
 object resTest = client.Post("/" + facebookFriendID + "/feed", parameters);
```

This is throwing the exception.  Do I need to set any special options in my app to allow this to post to friends walls and/or do the users receving the post need to accept the app first? Is there any other params I need to send?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to a friend's wall has been disabled

> Post to friends wall via the API generate a high levels of negative user feedback, including “Hides” and “Mark as Spam" and so we are removing it from the API. If you want to allow people to post to their friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag).

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception is pretty explicit: your app must ask the target user for an authorization to post on its wall, and the user has to approve it. Imagine how would Facebook it be if any app could just post whatever it wanted on anyone's behalf in anyone's wall.

Depending on your implementation, you will need to ask for the `publish_stream`, `status_update`, or even other permission.

> Do I pass this as a param? – CR41G14

I think it's more complicated than that, as you have to ask for the permission before acting. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743896/fbconnect-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this-action) for some information that may help you (here in SO there are several other questions about the topic, too).

Comment: Sorry this did not help either.  It is quite difficult to implement!

Answer (score 0):

ensure which authorization check the user has access to only his/her pages or whole application.

For basic authorization you can do like this

```
    [BasicAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       // code will go here
    }
```

For Anonymous

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       // code will go here
    }
```

> [BasicAuthorize] requires at least user should login
>
> [AllowAnonymous] Allow Every one to application

Comment: How does this adhere to posting to a wall?